# Custom rules in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to create custom rule for Outlook? I know i can import rwz file to outlook but I want to write a script-like rule with more advanced "thinking". is that possible? is there some manual for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found two links about this issue:

1. [Extending Outlook Rules via Scripting](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/A_420-Extending-Outlook-Rules-via-Scripting.html)
2. [How to create a custom rule using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292063)

I believe especially the first one would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is another solution to those already presented. Especially if you are not afraid of a bit of coding.

The solution has been presented under [similar question](https://superuser.com/a/784700/148049).

You can get it in full from Github [project p0r](https://github.com/mnmnc/p0r).

It is using **Powershell to automate outlook rules**. It allows you to create your own rule just by choosing destination directory and modifying the conditions in the if statement.

Example rule that depends on the string contained in email subject could look like this:

```
# MOVING NOT IMPORTANT MESSAGES TO DELETED ITEMS
# ! MARKING EACH MOVED ITEM AS UNREAD
    IF ($Email.Subject -match "not important" -or $Email.Subject -match "not-important" ) {
        $Email.UnRead = $True
        $Email.Move($DeletedItems) | out-null
        display ([string]$Email.Subject ) ([string]"Red")
        continue
    }
```

You can use all the fields in the Email object to create your own custom rule. All email properties have been listed [here](https://github.com/mnmnc/p0r#features).

Hope this will help you.