# Outlook Rules, “OR” Condition

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter, rules

Re-posting the question "[Outlook Rules - How to use "OR" boolean?](https://superuser.com/questions/405545/outlook-2010-rules-how-to-use-or-boolean)", as there is no accepted answer there, and it was Outlook 2010 *specific*.

I'm using Outlook 2016 now, but still facing the very problem in that Outlook 2010 question:

> It seems that Microsoft Outlook 2010 can only use the "AND" boolean when setting RULES. I find that very disturbing since even the lower end Windows Live Mail can use "OR".

Note,

- There is an answer that states, *"for subject line you can use both AND / OR Operators"*, but that is not justified with any source.
- The OP is actually wanting to filter by *sender* or *subject*
- and I need filter rules for *this sender* or *that sender*
- Creating two separate rules can be, if otherwise impossible, the answer, but also note the following comment *"At my work, there are so many lists and such that rule count is actually a problem. Outlook 2010 has a rather low rule number limit, so a reasonable filtering strategy would be nice."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook Rules - How to use "OR" boolean?](http://superuser.com/questions/405545/outlook-rules-how-to-use-or-boolean)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, did you just change that title just now, after seeing my question? Did you know that I've already included it in my OP? Did you know that the question is Outlook 2010 *specific*? Do you know that that one doesn't have an accepted answer? Do you think that it can magically have an answer after four more years without a picked answer? Do you know that answer 2 can be an answer, since time has passed? Do you?

Comment: Yes, I edited the "2010" specifics out of the title (added a outlook 2010 tag instead), to generalize it more, as it applies to more than JUST Outlook 2010 (as your question shows).  Yes I know you mentioned it, but it's just duplicate of that existing question (in my opinion).  "Do you know that that one doesn't have an accepted answer?"  Doesn't make it a different question.

Comment: "Do you think that it can magically have an answer after four more years without a picked answer?" It already has several answers. just because the OP didn't pick a "best one for them" doesn't make the other answers any less useful.  "Do you know that answer 2 can be an answer, since time has passed?" I'm not sure what you mean by "answer 2" exactly, but if you find an answer you know is wrong/not useful, feel free to down-vote it.  If you'd like to try and garner newer/different answers, spend some Rep and add a Bounty to the existing question.

Comment: Regardless of all that, keep in mind that it takes more than just my vote to close this.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter multiple items in the condition's text. These multiple items will be `OR`-ed.

Exit the field by tabbing or clicking elsewhere, and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> -<kbd>Tabbing</kbd> or clicking back into it to add another item.

Condition: 
Message body includes:  1-star [x] 2-star [x] 3-star [x] 4-star [x]

This will match "3-star" in the message body, but not "5-star"

Tested on web-based Office 365.

Comment: Please take a closer look at the question -- _"The OP is actually wanting to filter by sender or subject, 
and I need filter rules for this sender or that sender"_. The multiple items will be OR-ed only for message body conditions.

Answer (score -2):

Hiya I have done this before and worked like a charm
https://www.msoutlook.info/question/276

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with rules.